# Scala Spark - converting sign of a Seq[double] in a flatMap

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to change the sign of a Seq[double] inside a flatMap. I am getting type mismatch error.

```
import util.Random.nextDouble
var numbers = Seq.fill(1000)(nextDouble)
val nrdd = sc.parallelize(numbers)    
val mrdd = nrdd.flatMap(a => (a)* -1.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are simply looking for the `map` method instead of `flatMap`.

```
val mrdd = nrdd.map(a => -a)
```